# gcloud auth login - Authorization Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to do `gcloud auth login` on my google cloud, then copying the html to my browser, but get the following Authorization Error. Any ideas what it is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: solved by using: gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser